# KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP/DOWN changing functionality

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-tools

I have an app:
3D Cube (OPENGLES) with touch and key support. I'm using KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP/DOWN to zoom in/out. Method responsible for that is placed in:
**MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView**. My problem is, when I press the zoom out/int, it works fine, but I have also volume up/down function. Is possible quick solution for that?

code:

```
       @Override
   public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent evt) {
      switch(keyCode) {
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:   // Decrease Y-rotational speed
            renderer.speedY -= 0.3f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:  // Increase Y-rotational speed
            renderer.speedY += 0.3f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:     // Decrease X-rotational speed
            renderer.speedX -= 0.3f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:   // Increase X-rotational speed 
            renderer.speedX += 0.3f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:// Zoom out (decrease z)
            renderer.z -= 0.4f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP: // Zoom in (increase z)
            renderer.z += 0.4f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
             renderer.speedY = 0;
             renderer.speedX = 0;
             renderer.z      = -6.0f;
             break;
      }
      return true;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system volume control is performed by the [onKeyDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) event. Returning true in your class cancels the [onKeyUp](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyUp%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) event from being processed by the system but the onKeyDown has already been run. Override onKeyDown instead and it should work.

**EDIT:** After some research it seems that the best approach to override [dispatchKeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29) which should prevent both the onKeyDown and onKeyUp events.

Comment: @override for OnKeyDown method solved problem. 5 seconds of work. Thanks a lot!